# What would you use for your domain?

Tags: portfolio

I am struggling to decide. I have multiple domains. One for my username, one for my real name, one for a project I like to setup where I host different services for the community, and more :D

Now I want to build a portfolio or personal brand and a blog. Would you recommend to put it all under my real name or would you recommend to use my username? Or maybe separate the blog and the portfolio. The blog would go to my username and the portfolio to the real name.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

It is a choice of personal preference and a small amount of money. If you are doing business not using your real name you may need to file for a DBA to stay legal in the U.S.A. An LLC is an option as well.

Either way, what we would recommend to our clients in this situation would be to combine it all under one name. Perhaps your real name if trying to become an employee, however, a username/dba/fictitious name if trying to run a business as an independent contractor and the made up name you feel you must have is available.

If you get a large amount of traffic to each domain, then you can also forward them to whichever main domain you choose to use.